# How can I filter this data out of a message with regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have messages formatted like this:

```
Character Name > <url=fitting:11978:14240;1:31366;1:1447;2:31952;1:14136;1:31378;1:2104;2:3608;4:12058;1:31932;1:2488;6:29001;5::>He Dead :(</url> asdf asefase 351235125
```

I want to filter out this:

```
:11978:14240;1:31366;1:1447;2:31952;1:14136;1:31378;1:2104;2:3608;4:12058;1:31932;1:2488;6:29001;5::
```

If I just limit it to numbers and `;` and `:` it will also catch numbers in the message and the timestamp on the message (another property occasionally there) so that doesn't seem to work properly.

I also want to be able to grab the data if it's the only thing in the input:

```
:11978:14240;1:31366;1:1447;2:31952;1:14136;1:31378;1:2104;2:3608;4:12058;1:31932;1:2488;6:29001;5::
```

Sometimes the first `:` isn't there as well.

Any ideas how best to filter this out? I'm a bit stumped with the regex.

**EDIT: Another example**

```
[04:04:55] Morpheus Deathbrew > is this okay? it's cap stable  <url=fitting:11978:14240;1:2032;1:31366;1:1447;2:2281;1:31952;1:14136;1:31378;1:2104;1:3608;4:12058;1:2488;6:29001;6::>He Dead :(</url>
```

I think most solutions would match the timestamp too in some cases. I'd also like to POSSIBLY be able to still handle it if it has :: in the chat message. Maybe match if it has :: and then numbers? And also at least one `;` between the : and the ::?

Comment: Is `::` always at the end of the pattern or could it not exist or be something completely different?

Comment: I'm fairly certain :: is always there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like

```
/[\d:;]+::/
```

- `[\d:;]+` matches any digit `:` or `;`. The `+` quantifier is greedy and will consume every `::` that may occure in the body until the last `::`
- `::` matches the last `::`

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/bT3aK8/3)

---

**EDIT**

Enforcing format

```
/:?(\d+:\d+;)+\d+::/
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/bT3aK8/4)

Comment: Problem with this is that if `::` doesn't exist it will match this pattern anywhere in the string.

Comment: I do think it needs to be a bit more specific :/

Comment: Okay, you're matching any digit. This looks good. If you look at the sequence there is a pattern, individual groups are separated by `;` for example `3:2049`. Is there some way to enforce that format as well? Sorry to keep making this more complex, but I'm trying to figure out how to make it utlra reliable and not match people's chat text as well.

Comment: @nu11p01n73R Thank you so much for your time :) If you have any improvements to make it more reliable I super appreciate it.

Comment: @ChristianStewart I have added an edit. It will enforce the pattern. See the demo link for example. Hope it helps you :)